# I am implementing in ASP.NetCore 2.1 MVC application Saml2.0 , no idea from where to proceed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml, asp.net-core-2.1, onelogin, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to implement saml 2.0 in Asp.NetCore 2.1 MVC application, the requirement is to implement Saml 2.0 with ADFS3.0, I tried from blog and installed nugget - Sustain.saml2.0, throwing me error with system.

> BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

How can I implement saml2.0 in asp.netcore 2.1? I am new to saml.

Comment: Did you use the .Net Core package? - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2

Comment: Yes after using sustainsys.saml2 nuget, the system.IdentityModel.dll cannot load.

Comment: anyone can share the blogs or links to implement using Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2

Answer (score -1):

You can implement SAML 2.0 in ASP.NET Core 2.1 using the ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 MVC Core package. The Package also support AD FS 3.0.

Project: https://itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2

NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/